# Reinstalling the uninstalled packages using a bash script to make things back to normal

Tags: ubuntu, bash, package-management

Well, I created a bash script which seems to work on my situation. Here I have installed a random small program to catch other error messages & saved it as "**ls.sh**" *filename*.

```
for package in $(apt remove hello --purge 2>&1 |
 grep "warning: files list file for package '" |
 grep -Po "[^'\n ]+'" | grep -Po "[^']+");
 do apt-get install --reinstall "$package";
 done
```

To solve this kinds of big time consuming problem:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'package-name 1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
....
....
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'package-name 2000' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Day by day, the number of "packages" to install decreases depending upon my internet speed and whether its SSD or HDD. We all know, fast internet + SDD = Less time. But that it's in my case. I have HDD and 500kbps download speed.

So every day I keep track of the number of the remaining packages to be installed in [this](https://pastebin.com/hruWCeYJ) way, where I read the last line number.

**Now my main problem is this:**

```
pranav@inspiron-5548L:~/Documents/command$ sudo /bin/bash ls.sh

<no output like it used to show before, but it is running though>
```

where I clearly don't see what going on. No output whatsoever. Here can't keep track of remaining packages to be reinstalled since I don't see anything. **Help me see it**. *It seems to be running but waiting for all packages to be re-installed and then only say something.*

Comment: You seem not on right way!  Have a look at `/var/log/apt`, try `find /var/lib/dpkg/info -mtime -1`...

Comment: your script consumes output which was meant for human consumption, therefore it is not deterministic in nature (around git they call it 'porcelain', see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/). This is not your current problem, but it will be in a short time. To avoid falling in this trap too, you better rewrite your script use programs with deterministic (called 'plumbing' in git) output.

Comment: @asdmin thanks, learned a new thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I clearly don't see what going on. No output whatsoever. Here can't keep track of remaining packages to be reinstalled since I don't see anything. Help me see it.

This can be understood in many ways. As I understand your question, you want to debug your script, and your goal is to see what happens during script execution.

This can be achieved by invoking bash with the `-x` switch:

```
sudo /bin/bash -x ls.sh
```

From `man bash`:

> -x Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

Comment: ... Yes, or `-v`! But whole process is subject to re-mind...

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, I deleted the files associated with dpkg which damanged everything. So in the end, I backup all important files and reinstalled the entire distro. Reinstalling all packages will take a huge amount of time. And not to mention, that even if do manage to reinstall all packages, there is **NO** guarantee things will work out the way it was.